# Cannot install tweepy to Python library from git

Tags: tweepy

I tried:

git clone git://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy.git
cd tweepy
python setup.py install

and I get a syntax error highlighting "clone"

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
easy_install tweepy 
pip install tweepy
```

PS:
before debian install 
run this on console

```
sudo apt-get install easy_install
```